# PHP - SQL parse statement error (unexpected T_LNUMBER)

Tags: php, sql, syntax-error, php-parse-error

Can anyone help me debug this problem? This is part of a php script which I want to run from cron. I've been looking at it but cannot figure out what is wrong.
The following line throws the PHP error "PHP Parse error:  syntax error, unexpected T_LNUMBER in... on line..."

```
$sqlreadstmt = $db->query("
select distinct 
rsdata.rs_variant,
rsdata.weeknumber,
rsdata.rs_moduleid,
rsdata.rs_objectidentifier,
trdata.tr_objectidentifier,
trdata.tr_testversion,
trdata.tr_plannedgate,
trdata.tr_vnvmethod,
testatussequence.tesequencenr,
trdata.tr_testexecutionstatus 
from rsdata,trdata,module,variantgates,testatussequence 
where rsdata.weeknumber="1339" 
and rsdata.rs_moduleid = module.moduleid 
and rsdata.weeknumber = trdata.weeknumber 
and rsdata.rs_reviewstatus != "Obsolete" 
and rsdata.rs_reviewstatus != "Rejected" 
and rsdata.rs_introbjectidentifieralllevels != "" 
and rsdata.rs_introbjectidentifieralllevels != "Unknown" 
and find_in_set(trdata.tr_objectidentifier, (select rsdata.rs_introbjectidentifieralllevels)) 
and trdata.tr_plannedgate != "" 
and trdata.tr_plannedgate != "Unknown" 
and trdata.tr_plannedgate = variantgates.gate 
and trdata.tr_variant = variantgates.variant 
and trdata.tr_testexecutionstatus = testatussequence.testatus 
order by 
rs_variant ASC,
weeknumber ASC,
rs_moduleid ASC,
rs_objectidentifier ASC,
tr_testversion ASC,
tr_plannedgate ASC,
tr_vnvmethod ASC,
tesequencenr DESC;
");
```

Comment: can you put the whole error?

Comment: Care to share the full error? Truncating it like that doesn't help us answer the question

Comment: Mismatched quotes `where rsdata.weeknumber="1339" `

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because an IDE with *syntax highlighting* would have made it obvious sooner.

Comment: mario, how do you get an off-topic question?

Comment: Not a 'simple typographical error' and can be reproduced - the case is that PHP does not support double-quotes without escaping. For the PHP experts this is pretty trivial but for learners (those are the people who use the site and need help) this is the kind of 'dumb question' that is not so obvious. Anyway, all good, problem is solved and still there for anyone in the future as reference of possible causes of that error message.

Answer (score 5):

Can you try this?

```
$sqlreadstmt = $db->query("
select distinct 
rsdata.rs_variant,
rsdata.weeknumber,
rsdata.rs_moduleid,
rsdata.rs_objectidentifier,
trdata.tr_objectidentifier,
trdata.tr_testversion,
trdata.tr_plannedgate,
trdata.tr_vnvmethod,
testatussequence.tesequencenr,
trdata.tr_testexecutionstatus 
from rsdata,trdata,module,variantgates,testatussequence 
where rsdata.weeknumber='1339' 
and rsdata.rs_moduleid = module.moduleid 
and rsdata.weeknumber = trdata.weeknumber 
and rsdata.rs_reviewstatus != 'Obsolete' 
and rsdata.rs_reviewstatus != 'Rejected' 
and rsdata.rs_introbjectidentifieralllevels != '' 
and rsdata.rs_introbjectidentifieralllevels != 'Unknown' 
and find_in_set(trdata.tr_objectidentifier, (select rsdata.rs_introbjectidentifieralllevels)) 
and trdata.tr_plannedgate != '' 
and trdata.tr_plannedgate != 'Unknown' 
and trdata.tr_plannedgate = variantgates.gate 
and trdata.tr_variant = variantgates.variant 
and trdata.tr_testexecutionstatus = testatussequence.testatus 
order by 
rs_variant ASC,
weeknumber ASC,
rs_moduleid ASC,
rs_objectidentifier ASC,
tr_testversion ASC,
tr_plannedgate ASC,
tr_vnvmethod ASC,
tesequencenr DESC;
");
```

Inside a double apostrophes you can't use other double apostrophes " without escaping them.

Otherwise in sql simple apostrophe is the string delimiter.

Comment: Yes, that was it - escape double quotes or use singles. Thanks. Everyone responded very fast, even with the negative scoring ;-)

Answer (score 4):

Looks like the problem is that you have double quotes in your SQL statement, which is closing off the string used for your query.  Try escaping the double quotes inside the SQL statement, or just use single quotes instead.

Comment: Yes, that was it - escape double quotes or use singles. Thanks.